# yii2 Pass two variables into onchange

Tags: jquery, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i am having trouble trying to pass two variables in an onchange in yii2. The below code doesn't work.

_form

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'commodity')->dropDownList(
             ArrayHelper::map(['empty'=>'Empty string'], 'id', 'value'),
            [
             'prompt'=>'------- Select --------',
              'id'=>'pcommodity', 
              'disabled'=>"disabled", 
              'style' => 'width:250px',
              'onchange'=>
              '$.post("/import-conditions/plants/listsspecies?
               name='.'" +$(this).val(),function(data)
             {
                 $( "select#pspecies").html(data)

             })      

                 here is the problem  

            **$.post("/import-conditions/plants/listsintendeduse?name='.'"
           +$(this).val(),function(data)'.'+$(category).val(),function(data)
           {
             $( "select#pintendeduse").html(data)
            })**

           $.post("/import-conditions/plants/listsorigin?name='.'"
           +$(this).val(),function(data)
           {
             $( "select#porigin").html(data)
            }) 
             ;' 
            ])->label(false);?>
```

This form information is passed to the controller here is the code for the controller.

```
public function actionListsintendeduse($name,$category)
    {
         $countMaindata= Plants::find()
                        ->where(['commodity'=> $name,'category'=>$category])
                        ->count();
         $maindata  = Plants::find()
                 ->select('intendeduse')
                 ->where(['commodity'=> $name,'category'=>$category])
                 ->orderBy(['intendeduse'=>SORT_ASC])
                 ->distinct()
                 ->all();
         if($countMaindata > 0)
         { 
              // echo '<option value="">Select intendeduse </option>';
             foreach ($maindata as $main)
             {
                 echo "<option value='".$main->intendeduse."'> ".$main->intendeduse."</option>";                
             }
         }else{
                 echo "<option> - </option>";
             }


    }
```

I am trying to pass two variables and have the controllers filter by those two variables.

Comment: what's the console error?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error

try this

```
$.post(
    "/import-conditions/plants/listsintendeduse?name="
        +$(this).val() + "&category=" + $(category).val(),
    function(data) {
          $( "select#pintendeduse").html(data)
    }
)
```

Comment: Your post was really helpful i have modified it to fit yii2.

Comment: $.post("/import-conditions/plants/listsintendeduse?name='.'" +$(this).val() + 
                                                                "&category='.'" + $(pcategory).val(), function(data) 
                                                                {
                                                                    $( "select#pintendeduse").html(data)
                                                                })